# When copy text from git-bash window through mouse selection, how to suppress ^C(ctrl+C) prints in git-bash

Tags: git-bash

[image]I'm using `git-bash.exe` (git-for-windows MING64 MinTTY) running on Windows 7(not from CMD).
When I select text on git bash to copy, it always trigger <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> （which will display `^C` in the next command line, it's a little painful）.

e.g.： When I left click down to select “`git --version`”, then left click up, in the next command line it outputs “`^C`”.

```
$ git --version

git version 2.9.2.windows.1

$^C
```

Has anyone ever encounted this issue?
And how to suppress the abhorring `^C` prints?

I download the exe file from https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases.
I tried the older versions, the results are same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I do not reproduce the error:

[image: copy]

Check your settings (right-click on the property bar) for the mouse action.

In [OP sunny-lunars](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6647569/sunny-lunars)'s case, [from the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38629085/when-copy-text-from-git-bash-window-through-mouse-selection-how-to-suppress-c/38629355?noredirect=1#comment64645381_38629355) it was [`YodaoDict.exe` process](http://yodao-free.sourceforge.net/yodaodict.htm) which was interfering with the copy-paste action.
Once that process is killed, no more `^C`.

Comment: I use the same configuration, it always prints ^C. No idea what caused this.

Comment: @sunny_lunars I suspect some other software which intercept your signal: check your processes and try to close/kill as much as possible to see if the issue persists.

Comment: Thanks very much, you're right. After kill one process, it works, and after open that software again, it still works. Many many thanks.

Comment: @sunny_lunars Do you know what process it was?

Comment: @sunny_lunars Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for  more visibilty, and for others to read.

Comment: Sorry, it's the YodaoDict.exe. Previously I kill the YodaoDict.exe first, maybe my operation is too fast, issue still reported, then I kill another process(Cisco jabber), this time it disappeared, so I thought it was Cisco Jabber. Now I'm sure it's the YodaoDict.exe. Could you kindly have a modify in the answer? Really thanks.

Comment: @sunny_lunars I have edited the answer and added a link to http://yodao-free.sourceforge.net/yodaodict.htm

Answer (score 3):

Because YouDaoDic.exe is watching the text you selected and trying to translate them, so a interrupt appears. You correct this problem by close YouDaoDic.exe

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the above answer given by user8107976 :
If you have any text translation program running then on text selection it will try to translate and since it is in a terminal (git bash, x-shell ect) the translation program will not be able to provide a translation and it will generate an interupt that will execute ^c